# How to write a TypeScript interface for Immutable.js objects?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immutable.js, typechecking

Lets say we have the following interface `User`:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  bag: Item[];
}
```

I can now define a React component:

```
interface UserComponentProps {
  user: User;
}
interface UserComponentState {}

class UserComponent extends React.Component<UserComponentProps, UserComponentState> {
```

This is great since now I can have type checking within the component, but there is a problem: user is not Immutable so it is difficult to prevent UserComponent from rendering when user haven't changed.

But if I store my users as Immutable objects, my component will look like this:

```
interface UserComponentProps {
  user: Immutable.Map<string, any>;
}
interface UserComponentState {}

class UserComponent extends React.Component<UserComponentProps, UserComponentState> {
```

How do I define an interface for this kind of objects?

Answer (score 0):

React's Component will re-render if `props` has changed, so the answer depends a lot on how you create `props` for rendering.

One simple example shall give you an idea:

```js
const bag = Immutable.List([{name:"bagItem1"}]);
console.log(bag.toJS() === bag.toJS())
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/immutable.js"></script>
```

What does it mean? It means, that if you store your `Item[]` with Immutable, and then render `UserComponent` like:

```js
<UserComponent
   id={1}
   name={"some name"}
   bag={store.getIn(["bag", "items"]).toJS()}
   />
```

Then on every store mutation, even if bag was never changed, `UserComponent` will receive new object for `bag` and will force re-render.

For `plain` objected props, you can consider using `React.PureComponent`, which will do shallow comparison for you, but if you need to pass array of objects then you generally have two solutions:

1. implement `shallComponentUpdate` method for you `Component`, where you can compare `prevProps` vs. `nextProps` manually, and return `boolean` which indicates if `Component` shall be re-rendered
2. Don't use `Immutable` for you store. Entirely! My company has done that, and we never regret. (You save 150kb too :) )

To replace Immutable, you will have to learn view practices of structuring and mutating store correctly. There are lot of [good articles](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/why-i-dont-use-immutable-js-with-redux-db05004f436)

Comment: Not using Immutable at all may be a good option, I do in fact think that it leads to unefficient apps, but you are not answering my question, which is how to have typing with Immutable (which helps to document and allows to do type checking).

Comment: _difficult to prevent UserComponent from rendering when user haven't changed._ This is the part I was answering to. 

I believe you misunderstand what interface does here.
There is no way that Interface could affect when component re-renders.

But if you still want just typing, then check Immutable's `Record`, examples [here](https://blog.mgechev.com/2018/01/18/react-typescript-redux-immutable/) and [here](https://medium.com/@alexxgent/enforcing-types-with-immutablejs-and-typescript-6ab980819b6a)